# Statistical analysis to interpret beta effect size for two different elastic net model

Tags: regression, anova, model, bias, elastic-net

I have two elastic net model and I want to compare their coefficient to say if they have any significant beta effect changes across these two models.

I thought of using Anova but realized since we don't know the variance associated with the beta effect, I can't use anova.
For example: B1 and B2 are beta effect sizes across two model.

```
E(B1) =B1
E(B2) =B2
B1 ~ N(B1, var1) 
B2 ~ N(B2, var2)
```

We can use anova if we have OLS since we know beta follows normal distribution and have estimated variance.
In our case beta is estimated by elastic net , is a constraint OLS. With constraint, the beta is estimated by a bias.
I want to know what kind of distribution beta coefficient will follow when they are estimated using elastic net and how can we compare the effect size across tissues.
For comparison:
let say:
We have a geneA with beta effect size across two tissue model. The two tissue has different sample size. For T1 we have 205 and T2 we have 463 samples

```
GeneA              T1    T2
beta effect size 0.456 0.1743
```

How can I compare beta effect size for this gene across the two tissue model and measure the significant beta effect changes, whether 0.456 is significant in tissue1 in comparison to tissue2 or there is no significant beta effect change for this gene across the two tissue model

Does anyone know how to figure out this.
Thank you.